# htaccess rewrite for yearly website

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, web, url-rewriting

I already looked a lot for answers and without satisfying answer I come now with my problem:

I am creating a website for a music festival, that is renewed every year. I would like to keep ancients versions accessible. So I have following structure:

```
/
2011
2012
2013
.htaccess
```

The Urls are almost the same every year. And I would like to make the actual website (now 2013) accessible directly under the root. For exemple :

```
aaa.com/festival/presentation -> aaa.com/2013/festival/presentation
aaa.com/programme/groupes     -> aaa.com/2013/programme/groupes
```

The user should not see 2013/ in the url, but access the page like he would type it in the bar.

I already tried some solutions like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 2013/$1
```

but it doesn't work : the page is not rendered as if I entered the 2013/ in the url (I use CakePHP and it says me, that the Controller is missing ; it looks for a controller named like the ordner in which my whole website is).

What is the good solution for my need ?

### Condition:

Another thing is that I would like to put the condition, that for some cases, it shouldn't rewrite the url, actually to access the old websites 2012, 2011, etc. for exemple :

```
aaa.com/2012/presentation does not -> aaa.com/2013/2012/presentation
```

Thaaaaannnks a looooot if you can help me !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/2013%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/2013%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ /2013%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Or it's possible to have it done automaically using the `%{TIME_YEAR}` variable, but it may be suitable for your needs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{TIME_YEAR}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{TIME_YEAR}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ /%{TIME_YEAR}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This essentially adds the condition that the requested URI *must* exist as either a file or directory in the `2013` directory before it gets rewritten as such.